# Moving specific table fields to a new table with PK/FK

Tags: mysql

I have a large table that I'm trying to break up.  For example I have a table called `CONTACTS` with a PK of `ContactID` and inside are fields for Addresses (AddressLine1, AddressLine2, State, etc..) and I want to move these addresses to their own table and have a PK/FK relationship.

I've already created my `ADDRESSES` table and created all the fields, including the FK for my PK `ContactID` in my `CONTACTS` table.

What method (query) is the best way of copying the address data to the new table (including the PK to the FK field)?  Documentation on the procedure would be greatly appreciated (I'm not looking for someone to write the whole query for me if it is long).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html

Comment: Can I do this with my new Addresses table or do I need to delete it and let the insert statement create it? THANK YOU!